I don't understand why cin worked differently depending on when I took the input
I was solving the hacckerrank challenge Arrays Introduction.
It was a very simple question. The input was two lines. The first had size of the integer and the second line had the integers separated by space.
Example input:
4
1 4 3 2

Expected output:
2 3 4 1

The question asked to print reversed array. My solution to the problem was as below:
int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int n;
    int arr[n];
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    } 
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<' ';
    }   
    return 0;
}

This did not work. The output I got was:
4 1
But doing one minor change to this solutions makes everthing okay.
So this works:
int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    } 
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<' ';
    }   
    return 0;
}

I don't understand why putting cin before and after the array declaration made such a difference in the output. If anyone can help me understand, I'd really appreciate it. Thankyou.

What answers did you get to this question when you asked it on the hacckerrank forums?  Could you please link to that question here, so we can read the answers there.  If you did not ask that question there, why not?

The issue is nothing to do with cin. The problem is that in the first example you use n before you have read its value, in the second example you use n after you have read its value. That's the difference. Don't use variables when they don't have a value.

You are using a variable-length array (i.e. an array whose size is not a compile-time constant). Standard C++ does not support them, but it appears that you are using a compiler that supports them as an extension to the language.
In C++, arrays have a fixed length that cannot be changed after the array has been created. This also applies to variable-length arrays.
In both programs, you are specifying that the length of the array is n. However, in your first program, when the array is created, n has not been assigned a value yet, so the value of n could be less than the value that you will later read from standard input. In that case, the size of the array will not be sufficient to store the values, which means what you will be writing to the array out of bounds, invoking undefined behavior.
Your second program does not have this problem, because you are creating the array after the value of n has been set. This means that the size of the variable-length array is being set correctly.
If you want an array-like data structure whose size you want to be able to change dynamically (even after creation), then you should be using a std::vector instead of a variable-length array. In contrast to variable-length arrays, std::vector is fully supported by standard C++.

As an addendum to Andreas Wenzel's answer, you should use std::vector when creating an array where the length is not known at compile-time.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    
    std::vector<int> v(n);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> v[i];
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << v[n - i - 1] << ' ';
    }
}


int n;
int arr[n];
cin>>n;

In this case n is the size of the array. Consider the following, n is the amount of items that need to be stored.
This means that you are basically saying "hey I want to get n amount of apples", yeah but what does n equal to? - The answer is nothing, you simply haven't given it a value yet.
Computers are very methodical machines, you need to specifically tell them what equals what before they can use it.
TL;DR - In your case you want to use n, but you didn't say what does n equal to. The answer that you've provided is correct because it first asks for a user input(let's say that it is 5), and then tells the computer "Hey this is equal to 5. So if I tell you to use this, use it as 5".You need to not only declare a variable but initialize it by giving it a value, usually by saying n = 5; or cin >> n;.
I am able to provide more details in case it was unclear.

Nitpick regarding "The answer is nothing" - It's not nothing but it has an indeterminate value and reading it makes the program have undefined behavior.
